# scale_colour_manual not working with plot raster

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster

I am attempting to plot a small raster using ggplot(gplot) with a manual color scale for the seven discrete values in the raster. However, scale_colour_manual does not seem to be working as expected (and as indicated in other similar posts on this and other sites) and instead resorts to the default coloration.

Here is the incorrect ggplot version:

[image: ggplot version]

Here is the correct coloration using R plot:

[image: R version]

Here is my sample raster:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11618932/map.tif

or

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11618932/map.r

And here is the code:

```
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
my_raster<-raster("map.tif")
my_color<-c("#177798","#D239A0","#A3E0AE","#D29D52","#8F4F3E","#917FD9","#6EC848")
gplot(my_raster) + geom_tile(aes(fill = as.factor(value))) + scale_colour_manual(values= c(my_color))
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You need `scale_fill_manual` for the `fill` aesthetic.

Comment: thanks! that worked!